# convert datetime with hours 1-24

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataset with hourly electricity price values for the month of November. They are downloaded from a database that stores hours 1-24. I am trying to replace these values with a 00:00 format, in order to create a posixct object afterwards.

```
MCP<-structure(list(MARKET_DATE = c("1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", 
                                    "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", 
                                    "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", 
                                    "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", 
                                    "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/11/2020", 
                                    "1/11/2020", "2/11/2020", "2/11/2020", "2/11/2020", "2/11/2020"
), MARKET_HOUR = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
                   12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
                   1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), DAM = c(59.52, 59.01, 59.01, 59.01, 59.01, 59.01, 
                                            47.59, 55.97, 59.01, 41.01, 39.01, 39.01, 39.01, 27.01, 41.01, 
                                            54.26, 59.01, 92.02, 59.52, 65.46, 59.52, 59.01, 52.46, 41.01, 
                                            43.09, 43.09, 43.01, 43.09), LIDA1 = c(59.52, 59.11, 59.11, 59.11, 
                                                                                   59.11, 59.01, 47.59, 53.43, 59.01, 41.01, 39.01, 39.01, 39.01, 
                                                                                   27.11, 41.28, 58.26, 59.11, 92.12, 59.62, 65.92, 59.62, 59.11, 
                                                                                   52.56, 41.06, 41.26, 43.09, 43.01, 38.79)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                             28L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried using the replace function, but it only works for the first 24 rows and not all the values of the column.

```
MCP$MARKET_HOUR<-replace(
  MCP$MARKET_HOUR, 
  c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24), 
  c("00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00")
)
```

I would appreciate it if you shared any ideas on how to replace all values of the hour column with the correct hour and hour format. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sprintf` to do the `format`ting instead of `replace`ing

```
MCP$MARKET_HOUR<- with(MCP, sprintf("%02d:00", MARKET_HOUR-1))
MCP$MARKET_HOUR
#[1] "00:00" "01:00" "02:00" "03:00" "04:00" "05:00" "06:00" "07:00" "08:00" "09:00" "10:00" "11:00" "12:00" "13:00" "14:00" "15:00"
#[17] "16:00" "17:00" "18:00" "19:00" "20:00" "21:00" "22:00" "23:00" "00:00" "01:00" "02:00" "03:00"
```

---

Or another option is `str_pad` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_c(str_pad(MCP$MARKET_HOUR-1, pad = '0', width = 2), ":00")
```

---

Regarding why it is not working in `replace`.  If we specify a numeric index as the `list` argument, it will only replace those positions mentioned in the position index and not others i.e. it replaces only the first 24 values.  A simple example is

```
replace(5:20, 1:3, NA)
#[1] NA NA NA  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

replaces only the first 3 values because those are the position index given in the `list` argument

Comment: I should note that part of the problem is that the database stores  hours 1-24 and not 0-23. I need the first hour to start from 00:00.

Comment: @Iro in that case, just subtract 1 from the MARKET_HOUR and use that in `sprintf`. updated the code

Comment: Thank you very much for providing these two options, `sprintf` seems very straightforward and easy.